# MS SQL - Insert Into Distinct Where NOT Exists issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key, sql-insert

I have looked at other threads at Stack overflow in regards to copying data from one table to another (but don't copy over duplicate data). But I keep running into this issue.

I have table A and B.

Table A has 7 columns with the first column as it's key index.
Table B has 7 columns with the first column as it's key index.

Here is the code that isn't working for me:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.A SELECT DISTINCT * from dbo.B
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from dbo.A
WHERE 'dbo.B.c1' = 'dbo.A.c1')
```

Unfortunately, I get:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_A'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.A'. The duplicate key value is (VALUE).

This being due to it being a primary key.

My question is: how do I copy data from B to A without copying data that already exists in A.

Comment: Why do you use `WHERE 'dbo.B.c1' = 'dbo.A.c1')`. This will insert all data. Please try using `WHERE dbo.B.c1 = dbo.A.c1)`

Comment: In fact, I recommend that you use unique table aliases throughout your query so that the correlations will not be ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single quotes denote string literals in SQL. So you are checking whether the **string** `'dbo.B.c1'` is equal to the **string** `'dbo.A.c1'`, which, of course, is never true. Just remove them and you should be fine:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.A 
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM   dbo.B
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                   FROM   dbo.A
                   WHERE  dbo.B.c1 = dbo.A.c1 -- No quotes!
                  )
```

Comment: Thanks, this sorted the issue! - sahalMoidu also mentioned this! I was close! :)